# Why monthly mean raster output seem to get multiplied by 10000?

Tags: r, mean, raster

I have various .tiff files (3 files per month (e.g. 20060103.tif, 20060113.tif, 20060124.tif, 20070203.tif. 20070213.tif, 20070224.tif...etc). I am calculating monthly mean using following code in R. But the problem is that the cell values of tiff files is in the range 0-1 but the final output of the code has cell values in the range 0-10000. I also checked it manually. For example, a cell whose monthly mean output should be .1265 has monthly mean as 1265. I don't understand that in which step, the values are getting multiplied by 10000 and how? I do not want these values to get multiplied by 10000. I want only mean. Could anyone please help.

```
setwd("D:/Data")
library(raster)
rast <- list.files(path="D:/Data/",pattern='.*tif',full.names=TRUE)
rast[1:519]
s <- stack(rast)
names(s)[1:519]
grp = substr(names(s),2,7)        
grp[1:519]
alb_mean <- stackApply(s, grp, mean)
names(alb_mean)[1:519]
for(n in names(alb_mean)){writeRaster(alb_mean[[n]], paste0(n,".tif"))}
list.files(path=".",pattern=".tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, share your data source.
Sometimes the authors multiply values by some coefficient intentionally. Thus they have integers instead of floats.